# How to route depending on GET variables in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to route by getting the variable name from the URL. This variable will be append to the URL using a `select`.

So my URL will be like: `example.com/?city=Montreal`

In the route.php, I have:

```
Route::get('/?city={name}', 'HomeController@filterHome' );
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@home' );
```

and in the `HomeController.php` I have

```
public function home(){
    $nom= Nom::get();
    return View::make('home.index')->with('nom', $nom);
}

public function filterHome($place){
    $nom = Nom::where('place', '%LIKE%', $place)->get();
    return View::make('home.index')->with('nom', $nom);
}
```

But this don't seem to work. What is the best way to route in Laravel in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put a query string in a route definition.

This can be handled easily with one route and one function:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@home' );

public function home(){
  $nom= Nom::query();

  if(Input::get('city')) {
    $nom->where('place', 'LIKE', '%' . Input::get('city') . '%');
  }

  return View::make('home.index')->with('nom', $nom->get());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Could you explain me the use of `Nom::query();`

Comment: @user1012181 `Model::query()` starts a Laravel "query builder". When you do `Nom::all()` it's doing `Nom::query()->get()` internally. Once you have a query builder, you can chain a variety of database functions - `where`, `groupBy`, `join`, `has`, etc. - together on it.